# Chain webkit animation

Tags: jquery, css, webkit

I would like to create a 'chained' animation that moves a div element on the screen to two different points on the screen, in two consecutive steps.

So if my div starts at (0,0), I would like this div to animate and move towards (100,100) in 2 seconds. After it reaches the latter destination, it then animates again and moves to point (200, 200) in 3 seconds.

Using -webkit-animation I am able to make one translation or animation, but I cannot chain the second animation to start after the first has finished - because I do not have a handle provided to be (an event, or a css class) that can give me such information.

I am happy to use a bit of javascript magic as part of the solution.

Here is some code to visualise what I am trying to do:

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

#box {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.translate1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in;
}

.translate2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
    -webkit-transition: all 23 ease-in;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#box').click(function(){ $(this).addClass('translate1') });
```

Edit: I am after a solution that uses -webkit-animation because it is currently the best way to display smooth native-like animation in osx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use jQuery and Modernizr, then a function like this:

```
speed = 500;

var vP = "";
var transitionEnd = "transitionEnd";
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    vP = "-webkit-";
    transitionEnd = "webkitTransitionEnd";
} else if ($.browser.msie) {
    vP = "-ms-";
    transitionEnd = "msTransitionEnd";  
} else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    vP = "-moz-";
    transitionEnd = "transitionend";
} else if ($.browser.opera) {
    vP = "-o-";
    transitionEnd = "oTransitionEnd";
}   

function animate(object, cssProperties, callback, ms) {
    if (!ms) {
        ms = speed;
    }

    if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
        object.css(vP+"transition", "all "+ms+"ms ease-in-out");

        object.css(cssProperties);

        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {

            object.bind(transitionEnd,function(){
                object.unbind(transitionEnd);
                callback();
            });

        }

    } else {
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {       
            object.animate(cssProperties, ms, callback);
        } else {
            object.animate(cssProperties, ms);          
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this: `animate($("#someID"),{"left":"100px"});`

Have a look at http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/legacy/ for a little more detail.

Comment: Awesome snippet of code Rich. The answer to my question was really the 'webkitTransitionEnd' event which I got to know about when it was brought up in this thread. The jQuery wrapper you have here is also quite awesome. I might try to spice it up a little bit and share it with you soon :)

Comment: That would be awesome – I'd like to make it into a proper plugin at some point, but haven't had the chance yet.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way to achieve this would be...

```
$('#box').click(function(){ 
  $(this).addClass('translate1').bind("webkitTransitionEnd", function() {
      $(this).addClass('translate2')
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ALhym/

There are some problems with your example code, I guess the real version doesn't have them, but translate2 has the same properties as translate1, and -webkit-transition: all 23 ease-in; is missing the unit on the duration, which is required.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery ([animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) u can do:

```
function moveTo100(){
  $('#box').animate({
    left: '+=100',
    top: '+=100'
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeOutBounce'
    },
    complete: moveTo200
  });
}

function moveTo200(){
  $('#box').animate({
    left: '+=100',
    top: '+=100'
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeOutBounce'
    }
  });
}
```

Ofcourse u can add another effects and type of easing.

Comment: Sorry Urosan if I wasn't clear, but I need a solution that uses -webkit-animation in order to get a smooth animation happening on osX. I am happy to use javascript helper methods that add classes, kick-off other transitions, etc, but not a complete jquery animation solution

Comment: Oh i see. Well there is also jquery webkit transformation animation http://plugins.jquery.com/project/webkit-transform if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

This is what animation keyframes are for. Below is an example using a hover pseudo-class.

```
@-webkit-keyframes Move{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px);
    }     
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: translate(200px,200px);
    }
}

div:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: Move;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fillmode: forward;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

And if you're interested in a longer tutorial on CSS Animations, here's yours truly presenting a full [CSS Animation tutorial](http://www.justin.tv/marakana_techtv/b/284732356)

Comment: You prompted me the idea to generate a keyframes css declaration using javascript at run time. The issue i am having with keyframes is that once the animation is over, it resets immediately.

Comment: That's what fillmode is for. When you set it fillmode: forward, it retains the final keyframe.